Is there a Qt event for when a QLayout has finished redoing geometry?
I have a custom class which extends QWidget and installs a vertical box layout on itself, as well as child widgets which are added to said layout. In this sense, it is a composite widget.
I have a QPainterPath as a widget member variable which represents the graphical representation of the widget and is drawn in paintEvent(). This path needs to be updated based on the positions and sizes of the child widgets, which are managed by the layout.
I have been warned not to place calculations in the paintEvent() function, so I decided to update the path before paintEvent() but after the layout has been computed.
As far as I know, however, there is no event representing the completion of layout calculations. The QEvent::LayoutRequest event is only called before the layout is updated. The QEvent::Resize event is usually called after the layout is updated, but only if the layout calculation was induced by a change in widget size.
I am looking for an event that is fired precisely when the layout is done being calculated, no matter the trigger.
So far, my best idea was to extend the QVBoxLayout class and emit a signal after the layout's setGeometry() function is done, since that is when the widgets have their final position:
class NotifyQVBoxLayout : public QVBoxLayout
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit NotifyQVBoxLayout() : QVBoxLayout() {}

    void setGeometry(const QRect &rect) override
    {
        QVBoxLayout::setGeometry(rect);
        emit doneGeometry();
    }

signals:
    void doneGeometry();
};

doneGeometry() then activates a slot on the widget, which immediately computes the new path to graphically reflect the new layout. This seems to work, but I'm wondering if there is a more idiomatic way of doing this in Qt.
Another idea I had was to intercept the QEvent::LayoutRequest and QEvent::Resize events and call the layout's setGeometry() function manually, followed by updating the path, but this produces buggy behavior.

If the parent size doesn't change, the geometries of the children don't change as well. Therefore, if you update that path in the resizeEvent() of the parent, you already have the geometries of the children updated. This, obviously, is valid granted that the children cannot resize themselves (for instance, by using a QSplitter). In that case, you may consider a common function that calls a single shot QTimer that invalidates the contents and eventually redraw them when required. It's acceptable to make related computations in the paintEvent() if they're accurately cached and invalidated.

@musicamante Since my layout may have widgets added or removed at any time, the geometry of the child widgets might change despite the size of the parent staying the same. I'm not sure but I think the LayoutRequest event reflects this scenario. But since you say I can put those calculations in paintEvent(), I'm assuming I could invalidate the path in resizeEvent() as well as in event() when listening for the LayoutRequest event. And then only compute the new path in paintEvent() if it's invalid?

Exactly: the computation would be made anyway both in a resize or layout request event, therefore a computation delay would happen in any case. Doing that in the above events would be ineffective, as there are occasions in which both events may cause further (and sometimes delayed) events. Since you only need the path for painting purposes, there's no point in possibly doing that before painting (which may not happen instantly) or even multiple times before any painting actually happens. Since the computation will always happen sooner or later, it is acceptable to do that in the paintEvent.

Note, though, that this is not an absolute rule. It may be acceptable to do the computation upon resizing or layout request, for example in case the layout is changed even when the window is not visible. In that situation, invalidating and doing the computation on the paint event may not be desirable, as could cause some annoying delay (and temporary freeze) in redrawing for a previously hidden window. That's why I suggested a QTimer: a persistent timer set as single shot could eventually do the computation in background with a reasonable interval, working along with the paint event.

In that case, if the painting happens before the timer has timed out, it will stop it and do the necessary computation (assuming the path has been invalidated). Otherwise, the timer will do the computation while in background, and as soon as the widget requires painting, the path would've been already computed. Still, that depends on the situation and the possible complexity of the layout (included nested layouts). I suggest you to take your time and consider the above, then write your own answer, detailing your reasoning and a basic implementation.

@musicamante I like the concept of caching and invalidation, and I like the QTimer idea (these widgets are likely to become deeply nested, and recomputing every path when they all become visible could definitely cause a freeze). Given that the LayoutRequest event only indicates the beginning of layout, I probably won't invalidate in that event, as the newly computed path has a chance of reflecting the wrong layout. My answer will likely be a hybrid of your approach and mine. I will think on it
